# Resque workers do not start due to middleware failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, worker

I have rescue 1.22.0 installed locally and on a server. To be able to catch MultiJson::DecodeErrors I added the following to my application.rb:

```
config.middleware.swap ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ::MyParamsParser
```

and added the class to my lib folder. In dev mode this works fine, I can rescue from DecodeErrors and I can start a worker using:

```
QUEUE=* bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

In production mode on my server the code itself works as well, but my god process was not able to start workers again. The error that occurs after god starts a worker:

```
QUEUE=* /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/bundle exec rake -f /home/deployer/apps/kassomat/current/Rakefile environment resque:work
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
```

I tried to patch my application.rb

```
config.middleware.swap ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ::MyParamsParser if Object.const_defined?('ActionDispatch') && ActionDispatch.const_defined?('ParamsParser')
```

but that did not work out. I do not understand why this works in development but fails in production.

Can anyone help?

Regards
Felix

Comment: Tracing the error show that it cannot find the middleware is the middleware code every getting loaded

Comment: The problem seems not my replacement class but the original ActionDispatch::ParamsParser. That's why I do not understand the problem, especially why it works in development.

Comment: @GeorigeF can you paste the Middle ware code so that I test it over on my machine

Comment: class MyParamsParser < ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
  def call opts = {}
    super
  rescue MultiJson::DecodeError
    [400, {'content-type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}, ["{\"error\":\"MultiJson::DecodeError\",\"message\":\"some message\"}"]]
  end
end